# Add zeros from one ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

```
package arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> ary = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("enter the size of the ary");
        int Arraysize = input.nextInt();         

        for (int i = 0; i< Arraysize; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter the element of the ary");
            ary.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> newAry = new ArrayList<>();    
        for (Integer num : ary) {
            if (ary.contains(0)) {
                newAry.add(0);  
            }
        }

        System.out.println(newAry);     
    }
}
```

The code which I have is just adding the zeros every time it loops but not checking the condition that when the `ary` has zeros then it should add zero to `newAry`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking if the array `contains` zero, if it is true then zero will be added as many times the loop will execute.

For example if the list has only one zero, then the 
condition `ary.contains(0)` will be true always for every iteration of the loop and  `newAry.add(0);`  statement will add zeros for every iteration.

You need to change the code to this:

```
for (Integer num : ary) {
      if (num.equals(0)) { //if the current Integer is 0 then add it
          newAry.add(num);
      }
}
```

Or if you are using **Java-8** you can use `Stream.filter`, to get a new `List` having zeroes from the original `List` in this case the `Predicate` to the filter will check if the current element is 0 else it will be ignored:

```
 List<Integer> newAry = ary.stream().filter(num -> num.equals(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Another approach is to use `Collectors.filtering` in **Java-9**, but the first approach is preferred:

```
 List<Integer> newAry = ary.stream().collect(Collectors.filtering(num -> num.equals(0), Collectors.toList()));
```

---

As per your comment, to remove the zeroes by mutating the original list we can use `Collections.singleton` to remove all occurences of zeroes:

```
ary.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));
```

Or we can go the **Java-8** way:

```
ary.removeIf(num -> num.equals(0));
```

If we want the non-zeros elements without mutating the original list, we can simply use a `!` in the `filter` operation:

```
 List<Integer> newAry = ary.stream().filter(num -> !num.equals(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This `newAry` will be a new `List` having only the non-zero elements filtered out.

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you for spotting it, fixed it!

Comment: Now, when I am trying to remove all zeros from the ary by using the same process it showing an error

Comment: If you try to remove the zeroes while iteration you would get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` so either use `Iterator.remove()` or stick with the approach I've shown.